# mypypath: Cannot find module named 'tzwhere'

Tags: python, mypy

I am learning mypy, and the first error I got is `cannot find module`.

My file is:

```
from tzwhere import tzwhere
tzw = tzwhere.tzwhere()
print(tzw)
```

It is runnable by python because `tzwhere` package is installed. But when I run it through mypy I get this:

```
mypy mp.py
mp.py:1: error: Cannot find module named 'tzwhere'
mp.py:1: note: (Perhaps setting MYPYPATH or using the "--ignore-missing-imports" flag would help)
```

How do I make it say `No library stub file for module 'tzwhere'` and deal with stub files instead of `Cannot find module`?

Comment: are you using `virtualenv`?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov i am using `pipenv`.

Comment: the problem may be that you've installed `mypy` globally (and calling it from there) and `tzwhere` is installed in your local environment

Answer (score 4):

In order for mypy (and other PEP 484 compliant tools) to understand how to type a given module, it must be able to find stubs for that module somewhere.

Mypy (if we simplify slightly) checks essentially two different places for stubs:

1. It checks a local copy of [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed), which is a repository of type hints for the standard library and popular 3rd party libraries. (A copy of typeshed is automatically installed alongside mypy.)
2. It checks if the package itself is [bundling type hints](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installed_packages.html) (e.g. if the package is a PEP 561 compliant package).

Unfortunately, it seems that tzwhere is doing neither of these things: I can't find it on typeshed; it doesn't appear to be bundling types. As a result, mypy will not be able to accurately type check code using tzwhere.

You have three main options:

1. Just suppress the error message by adding a `# type: ignore` annotation to the import. Note that this will introduce some dynamism into your code: any variable/function you use from tzwhere will be assumed to be of type `Any`.
2. Create type stubs for the module, store it in a folder somewhere, and point the `MYPYPATH` environment variable at that folder. Note that this will require a little bit of detective work on your part. [More details on how mypy finds imports here](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#how-imports-are-found).
3. If you want to share your work from step 2 with others, either submit a pull request to typeshed with your stubs or submit a pull request with tzwhere itself to turn it into a PEP 561 compliant package. Make sure you get an ok from the author of the library before doing either of these things.